# Absolute positioning of div without overlapping div above

Tags: css, html, position, absolute

I have a div that I wish to position at the bottom of the webpage. I can achieve this using `position:absolute`. However, I don't want it to overlap the div above when the window is made smaller. This was achieved by changing it to `position:relative` however as expected it does not stay on the bottom of the page on bigger screens.

Is there a way in which this is possible?

Current CSS

```
position:relative; 
bottom:0; 
background-image:url('.......'); 
background-repeat:repeat-x; 
background-position:bottom;
width:100%;
```

An example of what I was explaining.

[image]

Comment: next to positioning you can also try css z-index:; and overflow:hidden; but without the html this is just a guess. so html or even a jsfiddle.net would be helpful to help

Comment: Posting your HTML would be more useful than just describing it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the window becomes smaller, use `media queries` for that particular resolution or a resolution lesser than that and apply a `display:none;` to that div with the class that has a position absolute, if you do not want it to display or `z-index:0;` or `z-index:-1;` if you want to show it below the contents div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: good idea. Thank you. I am going to do relative positioning for smaller screens then absolute for the larger resolutions.

Answer (score 6):

As for me, the best idea is through creating a container DIV for all page content (stretch it to fit all screen using popular practices). Then you can put your footer to the bottom of this container by setting **position: absolute** and **bottom: 0**, and don't forget to set **padding-bottom: height of your footer** to the container. This will prevent overlapping your footer by content of the page.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this before. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Try giving `min-height` to `DIV` above footer `DIV`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `margin-bottom` of the height of the absolute element on the upper `div`. This way, your absolute positioned element will overflow with the margin instead of the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you should revert back to **position: absolute**, then try giving it a low z-index value, such as **z-index: -1**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, wanted all the div children to sit at the bottom of the parent’s.

I gave each of the div a classname (service) and then...

```
.service{
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: column;
Justify-content: flex-end;
}
```